# Comparison problem in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

#### Problem: Comparison

On Windows, a path can only be approximately 256 characters long, ClearCase will be affected by this limitation.

#### Known Solution known:

> it is a bug of windows that file with very long path cannot be compared & not ClearCase's.
>
> We can only avoid this problem by shortening our path (shorten or `label/branch/foldername/filename`).

#### Issue

I cannot shorten them because of several reasons.
So is there anyway that files in ClearCase which exceeds 256 chars can be compared?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21120400):

> It applies for Windows 95 but the problem still exists with NT/2000/XP/2003.

For Windows Vista/7, the limit is <del>much higher (4096, if memory serves).</del>:
... or not, according to the SF question "[Window 256 characters path name limitation](https://serverfault.com/questions/163419/window-256-characters-path-name-limitation)".

The usual workaround is to use the windows command **subst** in order to define an alias for part of the path and attach it to a drive letter.

> For example, you can map a network drive to substitute the MVFS drive and view path.
>   By mapping `M:\devuser1_servicing_processflow_integration` to `Z:\` will cut the path by 42 characters in this example.

Is there any reason you cannot apply that workaround?

Comment: The above comparision problem is existing in Winows XP,2003,Vista/7also.  Actually in our case Developers can only Create SnapShot View (as clearcase Admins restrict access for Developers inorder not to create dynamic views ), if we use Dynamic Views(where we can cut the path by mapping to drive as u said).

Comment: @Prathima: the `subst` commands works for both snapshot and dynamic views.

Comment: Subst command Works !! But History of clearcase is not being shown in mapped drive.Then How can we can see the history of file,or comapre the previous version and so