# Not able to check out files with long names in ClearCase Explorer

Tags: checkout, clearcase-ucm

I am not able to find checkout option for a file when I right click on it in ClearCase explorer while the option is available for rest of the files. 
The only difference is that the file I want to check in has a very long name ( I am using Windows ).
While I am able to check in via cleartool commands, it isn't possible from front end ( CC explorer) Is there any way to check out such files from CC explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible causes for a checkout unavailable:

- the path of the file itself is too long (combined with the long filename, more than 256 characters): a [`subst` command can help shorten the path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5582509/6309).
- or the file is *already* checked out.

A `cleartool status` can help distinguish between those two cases.
And a `cleartool lsvtree -graph aFile` (replace aFile with your long filename) can help see the file history and see if it is checked out (reserved or not) in another view.

Comment: Given the current scenario of my work environment, the subst command isn't possible. Is there any other way? Also, the second cause isn't the case.

Comment: @Shivani Why subst would not work? What is the current scenario of your work environment? Are you using a dynamic or snapshot view?

Comment: I m using snapshot view. Not possible as mapping will demand a change in the build process currently followed in my work env. Had it been a checkin of a significant no. of files, this solution would have been feasible, but it is certainly not in case of a single file. Thank you for the cmd though, it will certainly be helpful in someone else's case! :)

Comment: @Shivani Your workflow could do the `subst` just at the checking step, the a `subst /D` to remove that mapping.

Comment: I see! Will try it out and share the results soon!

Answer (score 0):

The window 255 characters restriction for file name can't be bypass or any sidestep if it.
You have the following options:
1. Try to shorten the name. Including all the folders that are the prefix for the view. Like vonC suggested.
2. Try create the view on Linux, and mount the folder to some shared area that can be seen in windows.
3. Use dynamic view, but Im not sure it will work.

Keep in mind, that other apps can also fail even after you solve it for clearcase as it is a Windows problem. Like msbuild or visual studio.